# Pip install database command is not working for Python 3.8.0

Tags: python, database

I have installed Python 3.8 and using it with Pycharm; moreover, I am working with mongodb for which i have to install "pip install database" which provides the following error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement database (from version:none)

Moreover, Pycharm proposed a solution:

> Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'E:\Python set up file\python.exe'.

Any suggestions how could I fix this problem and install it properly?

Comment: I guess there is no module named `database`. Probably you want `pip install pymongo`?

Comment: pip command is not working, even i added it in environment variable as well.

Comment: Sorry, pip command is working, but it is not installing "pip install database"

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to install. `database` is not a pip module, and this package doesn't even work with Mongo https://pypi.org/project/database/

Comment: I am doing a course on udemy, the instructor is working on a code with the same module as "pip install database" it's working for the instructor but not for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `pip install databases` but not `pip install database`

ref: https://pypi.org/project/databases/